# JDK 9 Compatibility

Tags: java, weblogic12c, java-9, eclipse-photon, netbeans-9

Currently, I have a JavaFX project running on JDK8 b181. The EJB's are also built on JDK8 b181 platform and deployed as an EAR on WebLogic 12.2.1. Everything works perfectly on NetBeans 8.2.

Now that we have decided to move everything to JDK9, I am not sure if all the technologies used above are compatible with 9. **I highly appreciate if any experts can advice me on how to approach with this migration, especially for application server and EAR components.**

I have done the below research:

**Server:** (Is there any vendor who supports JDK 9 for EAR deployment?)

- The latest version of WebLogic 12.2.1.3 is still not compatible with JDK 9
- The latest version of GlassFish 5 is still not compatible with JDK 9 (tried mapping AS_JAVA in asenv.conf file to JDK 9 and it did not work)
- Tomcat 9 web server is compatible with JDK 9, but TomEE plugin to deploy EJBs as an EAR is still incompatible with JDK 9.

**IDE:**

- Apache NetBeans9 is compatible with JDK 9. However, none of the enterprise modules (EJB, EAR) are migrated from NetBeans8. I have tried adding plugins in NetBeans 9 from NetBeans 8  repository, but still EJB projects only work on JDK 8.
- At the first glance, Eclipse Photon seems to be compatible with JDK9. I have added e(fx)clipse plugin and was able to add JavaFX support. Still I could not deploy any EJB's (as an EAR built on JDK 9) on WebLogic 12.2.1.3.

Comment: I assume part of the issue is that Java EE 8 targeted Java SE 8 as that was the Java SE release at the time.

Comment: Your question is far too broad, and you are providing no evidence for the issues you raise. It would be more appropriate to raise the problems you have encountered (e.g. _"I have tried adding plugins in NetBeans 9 from NetBeans 8 repository, but still EJB projects only work on JDK 8"_, _"I could not deploy any EJB's (as an EAR built on JDK 9) on WebLogic 12.2.1.3"_) as individual questions with supporting evidence for each.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for all the stack but TomEE 7.0.5 should run fine on JDK 9.